# How do I check if a Kendo Grid has had changes made to it?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I check if a [Kendo Grid](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html) has changes? I heard that there is a `dirty` property, but I cant find it.

Comment: If you have set `batch: true`, there is a `change` event which indicates whenever a change has occured.

Comment: Just noticed that you need to define the dataSource schema if you want the hasChanges() function to work(or the dirty property to appear on a dataItem).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Added rows will have the dirty property set to true and so will updated rows.  But, deleted rows are stored elsewhere (in the _destroyed collection).  Pass this function the datasource of your grid to see if it has changes.

```
function doesDataSourceHaveChanges(ds)
{
    var dirty = false;

    $.each(ds._data, function ()
    {
        if (this.dirty == true)
        {
            dirty = true;
        }
    });

    if (ds._destroyed.length > 0) dirty = true;

    return dirty;
}
```

Answer (score 39):

You can use the 'hasChanges' method on the Grid's underlying DataSource:

```
grid.dataSource.hasChanges();

$('#divGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.hasChanges();
```

Answer (score 9):

You can get notified and use the change event of the dataSource which will occur wherever you page/sort/group/filter/create/read/update/delete record.

To attach a handler to it use:

```
$('#YourGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.bind('change',function(e){
    //the event argument here will indicate what action just happned
    console.log(e.action)// could be => "itemchange","add" or "remove" if you made any changes to the items
})
```

Update: If the user has updated any of the models .hasChanges() method of the dataSource will return true.

Answer (score 3):

grid.dataSource.hasChanges will let you know if the datasource has changed

```
                            if (datasource.hasChanges() === true) {
                                alert('yes');
                            } else {
                                alert('no');
                            }
```

Answer (score 2):

The most convinient way to go is to use `datasource.hasChanges()`. However, this requires that the `Id` field is defined in the schema.

From the [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/haschanges):

> Checks if the data items have changed. Requires an [ID field] to be
>   configured in schema.model.id, otherwise will always return true.

If you do not have an Id field defined, you can use one of the countless ways to iterate over the data itself.

```
var isDataSourceDirty = function (ds) {
    var dirty = ds._data.filter(function(x){
        return x.dirty === true;
    });
    return dirty.length > 0 || ds._destroyed.length;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

worth a try:

```
var hasDirtyRow = $.grep(gridDataSource.view(), function(e) { return e.dirty === true; });
if (hasDirtyRow.length != 0)
{
     // grid has dirty row(s)
}
```