# Kendo Grid hasChanges, how can I handle readonly grids?

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I currently want to iterate about each Kendo Grid, and warn the user, if there are pending changes. For this I use the method [`hasChanges()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24146106/2441442) (I use batch editing):

```
$(".k-grid").each(function () {
    if ($(this).data('kendoGrid').dataSource.hasChanges()) {
        //Warn user about pending changes
    }
}
```

This works fine.

---

However, I have some readonly Grids which should return always false. The Problem is, they always return true (which is impossible, because they can not be edited).

I investigated the differences, and the problem is, that my readonly grids have not the `Model ID` in the `AjaxDataSourceBuilder<TModel>` defined:

```
.Model(model => model.Id(entity => entity.SomeId)
```

They must be defined to get `false` from `hasChanges()` on a readonly grid.

---

**My Question:**

1. Can I make `hasChanges()` work correctly without setting the `Model ID` each grid? It seems like a little overhead to me.

*alternate*

2. Can I check at runtime via JS, if the grid is editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo Grid has method getOptions() and there is property editable.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var options = grid.getOptions();
console.log(options.editable); //outputs true or false
```

I think schema.model.id is necessary because it's key property for CRUD operations. So you need it for hasChanges() to work properly.